# how to give space between two row?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to give space between the two-row in HTML file

which place add the code for space between the two row

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<div class="text-center">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle row">
    <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs col-lg-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="status" value="0">
      viaxors Payment 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs col-lg-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="auth" value="0">
      In Noxitix 2
    </label>

    <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs col-lg-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="auth" value="0">
      Soctixitx 3
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs col-lg-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="auth" value="0">
      Enjogs 4
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs col-lg-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="auth" value="0">
      Nedd Monons Duk 5
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs col-lg-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="auth" value="0">
      Escalation 6
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

output:

[image]

how to give the space between two rows in the HTML file?

help?

Comment: What do you mean by 'two rows?' If you want to space them out, you can add a margin-bottom to each item, or you can add top-bottom padding.

Comment: Have you tried `margin`?

Comment: @ LV98 yes I m trying margin I put the margin after the end of label ```</label> <div style="margin-top:10px"></div>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into consideration that a row starts here (according to your code):

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle row">
```

Then add the following to it:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle row" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
```

You can choose either margin-top or margin-bottom (If you wish space from above of below). In addition, play with the amount of px, and choose how much is good enough space for you.

Comment: I m using the ```style="margin-bottom:5px";``` 5 px margin my criteria thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, you can use `<br>` to add an empty line, you can try it.

Comment: I m trying that not work br tag https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZWl5.png

Comment: @rahul_patil  You need another one, please try again. E.g.: <br><br>

Comment: when I m using 2 br tag then too much space is added between the 2 rows that are the issue